# Site Columns in Sharepoint document libraries created by office365 groups

Tags: office-365, office-365-groups

We would like our project to be organized around an Office365 group. However we have some site columns with things like documentType, Client etc. that we would like to define once and reuse on each off the document libraries.

The problem is that each group comes with a document-library (so far so good) but they are all in their own site-collection so site-columns are not shared.

We could replicate the columns, but after completion of the project, we want to move [some of the] files] to a central library and hence we lose the metadata while moving because of this.

It is possible to create the groups in one site collection, or alternatively reuse the site columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a good case for using the content type hub. As far as I recall the content types and site columns from the hub will also be available in the site assigned to a Group / Teams

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I googled and found the hub. But do I need to "connect" the group to the hub somehow or is this done "automatically"?

Comment: It is a bit tricky, but it can be done by creating a new content type that is connected to the group.